# Unable to resolve dependencies for Android SDK Tools

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't install Android SDK Tools on Android Studio (version 2.3).

I got the following error,
[image: Unable to resolve dependencies for Android SDK Tools]

Is there anyway I can solve this error?

Comment: Updated Android Studio to 2.3 today morning and got the same error. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Are you able to launch standalone SDK Manager?

Comment: I am facing the same issue since today when I update to Android Studio 2.3 Yes, No issues launching the SDK manager. @MonishKamble

Comment: Have you tried updating from there? If yes, what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google fixed this, on the server side, shortly after discovery. It should work now.

Comment: I'm still not able to see update option on my android studio

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; no.

Google, for whatever reason, has decided to remove direct access to the standalone SDK Manager starting with Android STudio v2.3.
If you run SDK manager directly using @iK2H 's instructions, you will see that SDK manager does not detect Android SDK Tools v25.3.1.
It could be that v25.3.1 is only available via Android Studio settings, but this is broken for now.

Your best best is to upvote [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=244876) issue to draw attention to Google to fix it.

Comment: Definitely seeing this problem here as well. My local development machine will update to 25.3.1, but the most the Circle CI continuous integration server will update to is 25.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the terminal
2. $ cd "sdk path"/tools
3. $ ./android
4. Update

Comment: In fact, This SDK Tools 25.3.1 doesn't exist.  Show 404 page in dl.google.com -> [link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.3.1-macosx.zip)

Answer (score 0):

`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`
 or
`Build -> Clean Project` can help (let me know if it did)

Comment: Does not work for me (trying to update tools from 25.2.5 to 25.3.1)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am able to install 25.2.5 through sdkmanager but having problem upgrading to 25.3.1 (same error) like @aghidini.

Comment: Invalidating cache doesn't work for me. Trying to update to 25.3.1 on Android Studio v2.3

Comment: Does not work for me too. Damn studio is completely unstable.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows, search for SDK Manager and right click to 'run as administrator'. Attempt to the install it from there.

Was having the same issue and that worked for me...

Comment: Android Tools 25.3.1 are not visible in SDK Manager for some reason. The update is only reported in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the solution. Please try it out and report back on comments. Build is a success, but I still need to test by app to check for features and other possible side effects. Did not want everyone to wait until this is resolved. If this does not work or has serious issues, I am happy to delete this answer.

**PLEASE COMMENT**

The solution

1. I commented out

   > compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.y.z'
2. I also removed

   > com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing
   >   com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager
3. Upgraded the remaining `com.google.android.gms:*` services to **10.2.0**

This is my working `build.gradle` with no errors

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    def applicationVersion = '*****'

    dexOptions {
//        incremental = true;   // If anybody use below 2.2.2 android studio then please uncomment this line. It's by default true.
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        ....
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {
       ...
    }

    packagingOptions {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
 //    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:10.2.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    ....
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your SDK tools from old "SDK Manager" UI (You can find it at `<your SDK>/tools/android`) to 25.2.5 then update it from Android Studio to latest version (26.1.1).

For some reasons you can't see newer versions in SDK Manager UI.