# Unable to update "Dependent package with key emulator not found"

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Android Studio Update Error]

I am unable to update the Android SDK with the error "Dependent package with key emulator not found!" as shown in the picture above.

When I run the Android SDK manager; it does not show any update available.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733127/unable-to-resolve-dependencies-for-android-sdk-tools

Answer (score 0):

hello first you have download tools in the page android https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip after edit the file bash if you use ubuntu

`gedit ~/.bashrc`

and put in the top these two lines:

```
 export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
 export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Restart android studio.